# preg_match depreciated usage resolution

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I wrote this code almost 4 years ago and it ran fine up until I upgrade SQL/Apache last week.
Now I have an issue with my error checking, when a form is filled out correctly it still yields an error saying that the first name was not entered. If I comment out my preg_match codes it works correctly. I am no master at RegEx, so if someone could show me where my mistake is, I'd greatly appreciate it. I have a feeling it will have to do with delimitation.

```
switch (@$_GET['do'])

{

case "send":

  if (!preg_match("/\S+/",$position))

  {

    unset($_GET['do']);

    $message = "Position to apply for required. Please try again.";

     break;

  }

  if (!preg_match("/\S+/",$hours))

  {

    unset($_GET['do']);

    $message = "Position Hours required. Please try again.";

     break;

  }

  if (!preg_match("/\S+/",$fname))

  {

    unset($_GET['do']);

    $message = "First Name required. Please try again.";

     break;

  }

  if (!preg_match("/\S+/",$lname))

  {

    unset($_GET['do']);

    $message = "Last Name required. Please try again.";

     break;

  }

     break;

  }
```

Comment: Did you use Register Globals 4 years ago?

Comment: This is the rule I use for usernames: '/^[a-z\d_]{5,40}$/i. Feel free to modify the length {5, 40} to suit your own needs. Example of valid username: ThequickBrown100

Comment: What does `var_dump($fname);` before `if(...` say?

Comment: NULL @ Jonny 5.
Register Globals is turned on currently but I do not recall if the code was dependent on it back then as I've worked on too many projects in between.

Comment: @ Jonny 5, wow..... Don't know how I missed it but several variables appear to have been removed, including the first name, last name ones under the Post Section. There seems to be several bits of information that are missing. Thanks for the assistance, without var dump would not have put 2 + 2 together.
    $position = $_POST['position'];

Comment: After looking I noticed that the post was missing as well as id="fname". However even after adding these in I am still getting null on the fname, mname, and lname, number fields are going through though.

Comment: maybe I am crazy. But I saved a new file as flap.php with the same code I had in applications.php and edited the form action page name to the flap.php and now magically it works.... is there an a reserved name or something that is causing the problem?

Comment: After looking further I had to delete the other file and rename the new file as applications.php the issue appears to have been file corruption but could not fully confirm. Should I delete this question or mark the answer as file corruption?